# Time difference between two times in Hours in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, time

I need the time difference between two times in Hours. I have the `start time` and `end time` as shown below:

```
Start time | End Time 
-----------+----------  
23:00:00   | 19:00:00    
23:00:00   | 07:00:00
```

I need the output for first row as 20, for second row 8.

Comment: Please share what you have done in attempt to find a solution for this problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**Schema:**

```
create table a(Starttime time,Endtime time)

INSERT INTO a VALUES ('23:00:00','19:00:00')
INSERT INTO a VALUES ('09:00:00','19:00:00')
INSERT INTO a VALUES ('23:00:00','07:00:00')
```

**Query:**

```
select Starttime,Endtime,
 CASE WHEN datediff(HOUR,Starttime,Endtime)<0 THEN 24+datediff(HOUR,Starttime,Endtime) 
      ELSE datediff(HOUR,Starttime,Endtime) END Diff
FROM A
```

**Output:**

```
|        Starttime |          Endtime | Diff |
|------------------|------------------|------|
| 23:00:00.0000000 | 19:00:00.0000000 |   20 |
| 09:00:00.0000000 | 19:00:00.0000000 |   10 |
| 23:00:00.0000000 | 07:00:00.0000000 |    8 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATEDIFF`:

```
SELECT
    start_time,
    end_time,
    24 + DATEDIFF(HOUR, start_time, end_time) AS diff_in_hours
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Use `select case`

```
select case when start_time > end_time
    then datediff(hour, start_time , dateadd(hh, 24, end_Time)) 
    else datediff(hh, start_time , end_Time) end
```

Answer (score 0):

Query as per your requirement, just put your table name at the place of "YourTable"

```
SELECT Starttime
    ,Endtime
    ,CASE 
        WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, Starttime, Endtime) < 0
            THEN 24 + DATEDIFF(HOUR, Starttime, Endtime)
        ELSE DATEDIFF(HOUR, Starttime, Endtime)
        END Time_Difference
FROM YourTable
```